# Encoding in networkx

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, networkx

I can't draw a graph with networkx because of Cyrillic characters.

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
s = "СукупністьЇЄ"
G.add_node(s.decode('utf-8'))

nx.draw_graphviz(G)
```

And I'm getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/networkx-1.10-py2.7.egg/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.py", line 982, in draw_graphviz
pos = nx.drawing.graphviz_layout(G, prog)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/networkx-1.10-py2.7.egg/networkx/drawing/nx_pydot.py", line 257, in graphviz_layout
return pydot_layout(G=G,prog=prog,root=root,**kwds)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/networkx-1.10-py2.7.egg/networkx/drawing/nx_pydot.py", line 296, in pydot_layout
node = node[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I tried changing the line #296 in **nx_pydot** file to

```
node = node[:2]
```

and the line after that (#297) to

```
pos=node.get_pos()[2:-2]
```

given that a Cyrillic symbol takes two bytes, but nothing changed.

I'm using Python 2.7.5 on Mac and networkx 1.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I received help from a networkx developer, Aric.

According to him, the problem was that I was using the pydot interface to graphviz which doesn't seem to work with unicode

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

labels={}
graph = nx.Graph()

words= ["сукупність","вдача","волосся","колектив"]

for word in words:
    w = word.decode('utf-8')
    graph.add_node(w)
    labels[w]=w
graph.add_edge("сукупність".decode('utf-8'),"вдача".decode('utf-8'))
graph.add_edge("сукупність".decode('utf-8'),"волосся".decode('utf-8'))
graph.add_edge("сукупність".decode('utf-8'),"колектив".decode('utf-8'))
pos=nx.spring_layout(graph)
# pos=nx.drawing.pydot_layout(graph) # doesn't work with unicode
# pos=nx.drawing.pygraphviz_layout(graph) # this also works, pygraphviz
nx.draw_networkx(graph, pos=pos, labels=labels)
pl.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what is the problem but when I tried `nx.draw(G)` No error occured. So if you do not care about the graphviz layout, you can use it.

Comment: Thanks! Well, I want to draw a graph with labels. So, I also want to do `nx.draw_graphviz(graph)`
`pos=nx.graphviz_layout(graph)`
`labels["СукупністьЇЄ"]="СукупністьЇЄ"`
`nx.draw_networkx_labels(graph, pos=pos, labels=labels)`

Comment: And as far as I got it, I really need **graphviz** for this. Sorry, this is my first experience with networkx.